# react-native build ios release package succeed, but crash after installed

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I wrote a little program with react native, and in debug mode everything is ok. but came across some problems when I tried to package an ios release.

Here are my steps:

1. Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Change 'Build Configuration' from 'debug' to 'Release'
2. Configure the Bundle Identifier
3. Confirm the Signing Team is right
4. Product -> Archive -> Choose the archive -> Export -> Choose 'Save for Ad Hoc Deployment' -> select the development team -> next -> next -> everything works fine, an .ipa file was built.
5. use iTunes to install the .ipa program, but crashed when I try to open it

So I tried to debug this, unzip the .ipa file, found main.jsbundle was empty

[empty main.jsbundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ikOL.jpg)

I tried again in a new `react-native init` program, but the result is same

Could anyone tell me, which step is incorrect?

Here is my environment

```
react-native -v
    react-native-cli: 1.0.0
    react-native: 0.46.3
node -v
    v7.9.0
npm -v
    4.2.0
yarn --version
    0.17.10
```

#### Update 2017-08-14

@Ahmed Ali

Your doc is version 0.19 and my current version is 0.46.3

So it may not same.
Here is the AppDelegate.m

[AppDelegate.m file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3p3K.png)

Answer (score 1):

replace jsCodeLocation line with the following

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

then Run the `react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle` command in terminal from the root directory of your app

that's it

More info here [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.19/docs/running-on-device-ios.html)

Comment: Can you share your AppDelegate.m file ?